# Find distinct values between two subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, inner-join

I have a database table that contains data on the available patches for our customers' servers. There are two columns, `identifier` which is the identifier for each patch, and `date` which is the date of insertion for that data.

I would like to compare the identifiers from the past week to the current week's identifier. If an identifier existed on last week's date and doesn't exist anymore, that means the patch has been applied. If it exists on the current week's but not the past week's, it means it's a new patch. I would like to decipher which patches are new and which were installed.

For doing so, I built two queries, that are shown below:

```
SELECT `identifier`AS 'id1', `date` AS 'data1' FROM `patches` WHERE `date`="2015-02-02";

SELECT `identifier` AS 'id2', `date` AS 'data2' FROM `patches` WHERE `date`="2015-02-09"
```

I need to write some kind of join to retrieve the data for which identifiers have been installed or are new, and the counts of each. Both queries above work, but I need to compare their results.

The columns that I'm using look like this:

```
|  date  |     identifier     |
+--------+--------------------+
| 2/2/15 | 192.168.0.25-0001  |
| 2/2/15 | 192.168.0.77-1457  |
| 2/2/15 | 192.168.0.123-1329 |
| 2/2/15 | 192.168.0.84-2214  |
| 2/9/15 | 192.168.0.25-0001  |
| 2/9/15 | 192.168.0.77-1457  |
| 2/9/15 | 192.168.0.44-5311  |
| 2/9/15 | 192.168.0.78-1384  |
```

Currently, I have to do a lookup in Excel and compare them in a CSV. If an identifier existed before and no longer exists, excel puts a #N/D in the cell, so I then count  how many '#N/D' cells there are to get the number of patches that were applied. How can I get this information in SQL?

UPDATE: So, I tested shawnt00's answer and McAdam331's answer as well, and both of them worked. But now I have another question related to this problem:

Here in my job we make these patch reports every week. So, there are new patches and applied patches every week.
I'm building a webpage where the users (our employees) can log in, select one customer, an initial date and a final date and via ajax I load the requested data.
Everything is working well, the webpage is done, so is the log in system.
The problem is:
If an user selects only 2 dates (the initial and the final), how can I get information on the data in the "middle" of both dates?
For example, let's say the user logs in and selects the dates "2015-02-02" and "2015-02-23".
Assuming the database has data for both dates and also for the dates between them, which are "2015-02-09" and "2015-02-16", how can I use these queries you guys showed me to make the same kind of comparison but for EACH week?
In the example above, I'd need to get the number of new and applied patches between "2015-02-02" and "2015-02-09", then "2015-02-09" and "2015-02-16", then "2015-02-16" and "2015-02-23" and finally "2015-03-02", instead of "2015-02-02" and "2015-03-02". 
I tried to create some kind of loop with php to loop through the dates in mysql and `foreach` date I ran a query and summed up the numbers I got, in order to display the final count in each case, but it didn't work.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why you need join just `date="2015-02-02" OR date="2015-02-09"` in a single query will give you want you want.

Comment: No, If I put both dates in same query I won't be able to compare the identifiers.

Comment: show us expected raw source data and expected result please

Comment: What are you trying to compare? Do you want to see identifiers that are in both dates?

Comment: No, I want to see identifiers that are in only one date. Check my comments on @JNevill answer

Comment: I understand now. I have given an answer that checks for identifiers in the first date but not the second. However, it would be simple enough to alter to match the second week.

Comment: So that's not really how your dates look?

Comment: Yes, that is. The sample table above is exactly how data is in database

Answer (score 2):

It's not ideal to hard-code the dates and it would be pretty easy to make this dynamic (say relative to current date). I think this answer your question for the weeks you're interested in though.

```
SELECT
    identifier,
    case
        when count(`date`) = 2 then 'Not applied'
        when   max(`date`) = '2015-02-09' /* and count(`date`) = 1 */ then 'New patch'
        when   min(`date`) = '2015-02-02' /* and count(`date`) = 1 */ then 'Applied'
    end as `status`
FROM patches
WHERE `date` IN ('2015-02-02', '2015-02-09')
GROUP BY identifier
```

Summarizing is easy too:

```
SELECT `status`, count(*) FROM (
    SELECT
        identifier,
        case
            when count(`date`) = 2 then 'Not applied'
            when   max(`date`) = '2015-02-09' then 'New patch'
            when   min(`date`) = '2015-02-02' then 'Applied'
        end as `status`
    FROM patches
    WHERE `date` IN ('2015-02-02', '2015-02-09')
    GROUP BY identifier
) as T
GROUP BY `status`
```

For a range of weeks this might work if you don't spread out the date over more than about 52 weeks. I'm concerned about the user's date selection matching up with the week selection as represented by the date of a Monday.

```
SELECT
    identifier,
    case
        when week(min(`date`)) = week(:end) then 'New patch'
        when week(max(`date`)) = week(:end) then 'Not applied'
        when week(max(`date`)) < week(:end) then 'Applied'
    end as `status`

   /*   -- This might better work for all dates
        when min(`date`)) = date_sub(:end, mod(dayofweek(:end) + 5, 7) day)
            then 'New patch'
        when max(`date`)) = date_sub(:end, mod(dayofweek(:end) + 5, 7) day)
            then 'Not applied'
        when max(`date`)) < date_sub(:end, mod(dayofweek(:end) + 5, 7) day)
            then 'Applied'
   */
FROM patches
WHERE `date` BETWEEN :start and :end
GROUP BY identifier
```

Here's a week by week tally...

```
SELECT
    p.identifier,
    p.`date`,
    sum(case when pb.`date` is null and p.`date` < max_date then 1 else 0) as new
    sum(case when pf.`date` is null and p.`date` > min_date then 1 else 0) as applied
FROM
    patches as p
    left outer join patches as pb
        on pb.identifier = p.identifier and pb.`date` = date_sub(p.`date`, 7 day)
    left outer join patches as pf
        on pf.identifier = p.identifier and pf.`date` = date_add(p.`date`, 7 day)
    cross join
    (select min(`date`) as min_date, max(`date`) as max_date from patches) as rng
WHERE p.`date` BETWEEN :start and :end
GROUP BY p.identifier, p.`date`
```

Comment: Wow, this was a really clever way to think about it. I like the way you summarized the results too. I tested this in an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14fc63/5) and it worked great.

Comment: Great answer, man! Thank you for it. It seems to be working prefectly, but for some reason the results on SQL don't match with the results in excel, so I'll have to search for the problem. But this I can fix :)

Answer (score 0):

There's cleaner/tighter ways of doing this, but just slinging your queries into a LEFT OUTER JOIN and selecting only records that were present last week, but not this week, you would get:

```
SELECT
    `id1`
FROM
    (SELECT `identifier`AS 'id1', `date` AS 'data1' FROM `patches` WHERE `date`="2015-02-02") last_week
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `identifier` AS 'id2', `date` AS 'data2' FROM `patches` WHERE `date`="2015-02-09") current_week ON
        last_week.id1 = current_week.id2
WHERE
     current_week.id2 IS NULL
```

Update: Cleaned up a bit to remove the first derived table. This should have equal performance in MySQL since the execution path is most likely exactly the same. Although, I've seen MySQL make some strange decisions, so YMMV:

```
SELECT
    `id1`
FROM
    `patches` last_week    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `identifier` AS 'id2', `date` AS 'data2' FROM `patches` WHERE `date`="2015-02-09") current_week ON
        last_week.identifier = current_week.id2
WHERE
    last_week.`date` = "2015-02-02"
    current_week.id2 IS NULL
```

Also, since you are coming at this from an Excel/Vlookup mindset, you can think of it this way. If you put your Vlookup on your last weeks data and lookup to current week's data and then look for the #N/A records, that's essentially what you get out of the above queries. If, instead you want only the records where VLOOKUP would return a value in that scenario, then you can either remove the WHERE condition in the first query and change the JOIN to an INNER JOIN (or change the where condition to `WHERE current_week IS NOT NULL`.

IF you switch that and put the VLOOKUP on your CURRENT_WEEK to find records that are not in your prior week data, then just flop the tables in your FROM statement in the first query. CURRENT_WEEK LEFT OUTER JOIN LAST_WEEK, and change the WHERE to look for last_Week.id1 IS NULL.

Comment: You understood what I need. The #N/A records mean that that patch is new (if on current week) or was applied (if on past week). I only need to count how many #N/A records I have in each case.

Comment: Perfect, than either of the two queries above will do the trick. You can add aggregation in there too if you want instead of `SELECT Count(id1) FROM Blah blah blah` to get just a count of NEW stuff.

Comment: I ran your updated query and I got a SQL Syntax error, according to phpmyadmin: 

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'current_week.id2 IS NULL"

Comment: I just edited slightly to make sure that the table and field aliases lined up correctly. Give either of them another shot.

Answer (score 0):

According to your expected result it is that simple:

```
SELECT `identifier`, `date` FROM `patches` WHERE `date`="2015-02-02"
UNION
SELECT `identifier`, `date` FROM `patches` WHERE `date`="2015-02-09"
```

but question is then, why don't you just:

```
SELECT `identifier`, `date` FROM `patches` WHERE `date`="2015-02-02" OR `date`="2015-02-09";
```

I think you missed something in your requirements...

According to your comments :-) try this one:

```
SELECT `identifier`, `date`, COUNT(*) as `counter`
FROM `patches` 
WHERE `date`="2015-02-02" OR `date`="2015-02-09"
GROUP BY `identifier`
HAVING (`counter`=1);
```

Try to explain your goal deeper.

Comment: The point is that if I select ALL identifiers within both dates, I will get only the TOTAL amount of identifiers, wether they exist in both dates or not. I need to get the identifiers that existed on first week and doesn't exist anymore, count them, and then get the identifiers that exist on current week and didn't exist before (and also count them).

Comment: illustrate this by including raw source data for your expected result. I see you did expected results - that is very helpful, so now add the source from which data you want to get that result please

Comment: No, I added the SOURCE data. The expected data is HOW MANY identifers there were on past week and no longer exists and how many identifiers exist on current week and didn't exist on past week.

Comment: I ran your query and I got 3 columns: the "identifier" column, the "date" column and the "counter" column, but the "counter" column is full of 1's in all rows

Comment: ignore the column for now. does the result match your goal?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `NOT IN` operator. You can get all rows that happened on 02/02 and not on 02/09 like this:

```
SELECT identifier, dateCol
FROM myTable
WHERE dateCol = '2015-02-02' 
  AND identifier NOT IN(
    SELECT identifier
    FROM myTable
    WHERE dateCol = '2015-02-09');
```

To get the opposite, just flip the dates. If you want to get the count of identifiers that are in the first week only, you can use the COUNT() function on that subquery and group by date like this:

```
SELECT dateCol, COUNT(*) AS numFixedPatches
FROM(
  SELECT identifier, dateCol
  FROM myTable
  WHERE dateCol = '2015-02-02' 
    AND identifier NOT IN(
      SELECT identifier
      FROM myTable
      WHERE dateCol = '2015-02-09')) tmp
GROUP BY dateCol;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14fc63/3) example.

So, the opposite example (to get new patches) would look something like this:

```
SELECT dateCol, COUNT(*) AS numNewPatches
FROM(
   SELECT identifier, dateCol
   FROM myTable
   WHERE dateCol = '2015-02-09' AND identifier NOT IN(
      SELECT identifier
      FROM myTable
      WHERE dateCol = '2015-02-02')) tmp
GROUP BY datecol;
```

Comment: Thanks, man. This answer is also working well. As I told @shawnt00, I just need to figure out why the data on SQL mismatches the data in Excel. But I guess this is just some mistake with excel formulas

Comment: Yes, I am. The excel data comes directly from our tool (We use the QualysGuard solution here). So, there's no problem with the files.
I'm checking the database, I'll re-import the CSV files and check if there's some mistake.